# How to update UISlider's value automatically when core animation is playing without Timer

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, calayer, cabasicanimation

I've created core animation using 40 images (Per image stays in CALayer exactly 3 seconds). 
Total duration = 120 seconds. Each photo move from left to right with the help of `CABasicAnimation(keypath : "position.x")`. Now I've an UISlider. I want to update slider's value automatically when core animation is playing in CALayer. I used Timer to update slider's value like this 
 `time = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateSlideValue), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)`

Animation Code :

```
let blackLayer = CALayer()
 blackLayer.frame = CGRect(x: -viewSize.width, y: 0, width: viewSize.width, height: viewSize.height)
 let imageLayer = CALayer()
imageLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: viewSize.width, height: viewSize.height)
imageLayer.contents = nextPhoto?.cgImage
blackLayer.addSublayer(imageLayer)

let animation = CABasicAnimation()
animation.keyPath = "position.x"
animation.fromValue = -viewSize.width
animation.toValue =  (viewSize.width)/2
animation.duration = self.perImageLife
animation.speed = 1 // 1 is default actually
animation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + animationTimes[index-1] // animationTimes is an array like [0,3,6,9,.....]

animation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
animation.delegate = self
blackLayer.add(animation, forKey: "basic")          
parentLayer.addSublayer(blackLayer)
```

But it's not a better idea to update using Timer. How to update slider's value automatically when core animation is running without Timer?

Here is a small recorded video of my project. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SjaWJM_FEWp1TyR7fpQt8_IZdme_I2Vc/view?usp=sharing

[image: A photo which animated from left to right and slider's value updated using Timer.]

Comment: can you share your animation code?  You can certainly animate a `UISlider` value alongside the image animations.

Comment: Thanks for fast response. I've added animation code. Please check it again. And help me . @CSmith

Comment: If your animation continues then you can use CADisplayLink : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cadisplaylink

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can observe the properties you are animating and use those changing values to update the slider position. You'll have to use a timer to update the slider value at the moment of each frame change as you are doing.

Do you intend for the user to be able to drag the "thumb" on the slider to scrub the animation back and forth? That's another layer of complexity to the problem.

If that is your intent I would suggest using a `UIViewPropertyAnimator` rather than using a CAAnimation. Pausing/resuming/scrubbing a CAAnimation is tricky and not terribly well documented. I've worked it out in the past, so if you are determined to go that route I can dredge up some old sample code (probably written in Objective-C) and try to walk you through it.

This [project on Github](https://github.com/DuncanMC/KeyframeViewAnimations) (from 7 years ago!) implements both UIView and CAAnimation-based animations that include sliders that show their progress and can scrub back and forth.

It predates `UIViewPropertyAnimator` however. I also wrote a much [**simpler demo of UIViewPropertyAnimator**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/UIViewPropertyAnimator-test/tree/master/UIVIew%20PropertyAnimator%20test) when it first came out. It is probably written for an older version of Swift however.

Comment: Yes. I have intend for the user to be able to drag the "thumb" on the slider to scrub the animation back and forth. I already did it using CAAnimation. but it's working when I move the slider forward and backward direction. But slider's value didn't update automatically without touching. You can share old sample code. It would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out.

Comment: Is there any approach to update slider's value automatically without Timer?

Comment: No, I don't think there is.